# SVG.js plugins and RequireJS

Tags: svg, requirejs, amd

I am trying to write an [SVG.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.js) plugin to create some dynamic graphics. The site I want to use it in uses requireJS via django-require.

I am struggling to get the plugins to augment the `SVG` object, exported by SVG.js, properly.

The plugin is modelled after [svg.path.js](https://github.com/otm/svg.path.js), another SVG.js plugin, and looks something like this:

```
(function() {

    SVG.extend(SVG.Path, {
        myGraphicType: function(p){
            return this;
        }
    });

}).call(this);
```

My plugin will depend on `svg.path` and `svg`. `svg.path` also depends on `svg`. The `shim` entry in the requireJS config looks like:

```
shim: {
    'svg-0.32' : {
        exports: 'SVG'
    },
    'svg.path': { 
        deps: ['svg-0.32']
    },
    'svg.myplugin': { //My plugin!
        deps: ['svg-0.32', 'svg.path']
    }
}
```

The main app is `defined()` to depend on both `svg` and `svg.myplugin`. However, when I come to use the plugin like this:

```
var myGraphic = SVG.path().myGraphicType()
```

I am told that `SVG` is not defined in the `svg.myplugin.js` file.

What is the right way to include plugins like this using requireJS?

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle file and will take a look at that

Comment: Sorry, I was suddenly out of computer range for a while. Thanks for the offer :-)

Comment: Also interested in this question. I'm trying to include both SVG.js and svg.textwrap.js plugin inside my module. I can use SVG.js inside this module, but inside plugin SVG is undefined as a result it can't extend SVG object.